# SingalR not sending message from client to server

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I have serup a small web api project to send/receive messages on ASP.NET6 and I have wanted to send first a test to the server and see if it worked but I dont know why it doesn't trigger the Hub's Action method...

First i have written the client class like this and used SendAll method

```
    public class SignalrMessenger
        {
            Task ReceiveTask;
           // public Func<string,string,Tuple<string, string>> GetMessage;
            public bool StayConnected { get; set; }
            public delegate void MessageReceived(object Sender, ReceivedMessageEventArgs e);
            public event EventHandler<ReceivedMessageEventArgs> ReceivedMessageEventHandler;
            HubConnection connection { get; }
            public SignalrMessenger(string url= "https://localhost:7116/Chat")
            {//"http://127.0.0.1:8088/"
                 connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
                    .WithUrl(url, options => { options.UseDefaultCredentials = true; })
                    .Build();
            }
            public async Task StartListening()
            {
                await Task.Run(()=>ReceiveTask);
                connection.Closed += async (error) =>
                {
                    await Task.Delay(new Random().Next(0, 5) * 1000);
                    await connection.StartAsync();
                };
            }
    
            public async Task<bool> Connect()
            {
                Task conTask = connection.StartAsync();
                return await Task<bool>.Run(()=>conTask.ContinueWith(task => {
                    if (task.IsFaulted)
                    {
                        throw task.Exception.GetBaseException();
                    }
                    ReceiveTask = Listen();
                    
                   return true;
    
                }));
            }
    
            
    
            public bool Send(string username, SignalrMessageMetadata message)
            {
    
                try
                {
                    connection.InvokeAsync("SendMessage", username,message);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
            
            }
            public bool SendAll(SignalrMessageMetadata message)
            {
    
                try
                {
                    connection.InvokeAsync("SendMessageToAll",message);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
            
            }
    
            public  Task SendMessageEvent(string user, SignalrMessageMetadata message)
            {
                ReceivedMessageEventHandler(this,new ReceivedMessageEventArgs { Message = message, UserName =user });
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }
    
            public async Task Listen()
            {
                //while (StayConnected)
                //{
                    connection.On<string, SignalrMessageMetadata>("ReceiveMessage", (user,   message) =>
                    {
                        Func<string, SignalrMessageMetadata, Tuple<string, SignalrMessageMetadata>> funcReceiver = (usern, msg) =>
                        {
                            return new Tuple<string, SignalrMessageMetadata>(usern, msg);
                        };
                        SendMessageEvent(user,message);
                    });
                //}
            }
        }
```

and my server configuration is this

```
app.UseRouting();
//app.MapControllers();

app.UseEndpoints(endpoint => {
    endpoint.MapControllers();  
    endpoint.MapHub<CommunicationServiceHub>("/Chat");
});
```

````
{
    public AccountServices _AccountServices { get; set; }
    public CommunicationServiceHub(AccountServices accountServices)
    {
        _AccountServices = accountServices;
    }

    public async Task SendMessage(string username, SignalrMessageMetadata message)
    {
        var authtorizedUsed =
             (await _AccountServices.IsUserVerified(username)).Data 
                        as Shared.Models.AuthorizedUserResponseModel;
        
        if (authtorizedUsed.IsAuthorized())
        {
           await Clients.User(username).SendAsync("ReceiveMessage",GetUserName(),message);
        }
        
    }
    public async Task SendMessageToAll(SignalrMessageMetadata message)
    {
        //if (authtorizedUsed.IsAuthorized())
        //{
            await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", GetUserName(), message);
        //}
    }
    public string? GetUserIdentifier()
    {
        return Context.UserIdentifier;
    }

    public string GetConnectionID()
    {
        return Context.ConnectionId;
    }
    public string? GetUserName()
    {
        return Context.User?.Identity?.Name;
    }
}```
````

Comment: it gets stucks on 
                await connection.StartAsync(); call somehow it doesnt throws and exception(SignalrMessenger.Connect().GetAwaiter().GetResult();)

Comment: do not use `localhost`, instead use the actual IP or FQDN of your server

Comment: @Jason so i need to port forward the project´s port and use my ip?